# Force Gmail into mobile mode

Tags: gmail

Sometimes I need to quickly get into Gmail on a not-so-great connection, send a message (or get one I know was just sent to me), and get out. The mobile browser interface is perfect for that.

Is there an URL I can use (in a shortcut) that will get me directly to the mobile interface no matter what my real user agent happens to be?

For that matter, I suppose that the simple HTML interface that I sometimes get offered when Gmail has spent many minutes trying to start up could also be useful. Is there a URL or other way to get to that directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL http://m.gmail.com/ will take you to the Gmail mobile interface.

The URL https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html will take you to the basic HTML interface.

Comment: [mail.google.com/mail/?ui=mobile](https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=mobile) works too.

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/x/ also works for getting to HTML-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember how I found it, but I have had this URI saved from long ago:
https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/391/#tl/Inbox

It still works, although some features may have been removed. For example, I could have sworn that I could attach files through this interface, but right now I do not know how to.

Comment: That's a nice finding. I see the `391` is actually the account identifier and if you log into multiple accounts it changes, you can just set it to `111` and it upadtes to the first available account nonetheless. I'm gonna be using this in desktop browsers who have sidebars.

Comment: The shortest URL that works seems to be https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/